# Combine Maps with same key, into a List<Map, List<dynamic>> value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a logic crisis where I cannot come up with a solution to, merge maps through there keys. Basically I to have one map for one key, and the values of this identical keys should be as a list.

From this map ->

```
List<Map<int, dynamic>> myMap = [{1: 88550}, {1: 89887}, {1: 93297}, {1: 93297}, {1: 93297}, {1: 94863}, {2: 95141}, {2: 95141}, {2: 110110},];
```

I want a solution like this (for example) ->

```
[
{1: [88590, 8832, 2342, 234234]},
{2: [88590, 8832, 2342, 234234]},
]
```

tried to google and stackOverflow for a while, I still couldn't come up with a solution. Thanks

Comment: it is not helping me. Sorry

Comment: Do you really want the output to be a `List` where each element is a `Map` with a single key, or do you want the output to be a single `Map` that contains all keys?  In your example, why do keys `1` and `2` have the same `List`s of values?  Since your example is unclear, I'm not exactly sure what you want, but perhaps my [`mergeMaps`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartbag/latest/collection/mergeMaps.html) function could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
  List<Map<int, dynamic>> myMap = [{1: 88550}, {1: 89887}, {1: 93297}, {1: 93297}, {1: 93297}, {1: 94863}, {2: 95141}, {2: 95141}, {2: 110110},];
  Map<int, List<dynamic>> consolidatedMap = {};
  List<Map<int, List<dynamic>>> consolidatedList = [];
  
  for(Map<int, dynamic> item in myMap){
    for(int key in item.keys){
      if(consolidatedMap[key] == null){
        consolidatedMap[key] = [item[key]];
      } else{
        (consolidatedMap[key] as List).add(item[key]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  for(int key in consolidatedMap.keys){
    consolidatedList.add({key: consolidatedMap[key]!.toSet().toList()});
  }
  
  print(consolidatedList);
```

Comment: would you make a youtube video explaining the login behind ??

Comment: Thanks, I'm not into making videos, but I can explain it to you on a screen share. You can contact me via LinkedIn!

Comment: sure, will do that, I will text you